# react-jsonschema-form input box out of focus when ObjectFieldTemplate is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I have `rjsf` version `^5.0.0-beta.10` installed in `package.json` and am able to render a proper `Form` using `react-jsonschema-form`. The problem is that I'm using `ObjectFieldTemplate` and every time I enter a character in one of the string input boxes, the box goes out of focus and I have to click on the box again to be able to type anything.

I have read https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/2106, which suggested me to move the `ObjectFieldTemplate` outside of the custom `Form` definition. I did that and it does not work. I have also read [Custom widget with input loses focus in react-jsonschema-form when formData is passed as a prop to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924447/custom-widget-with-input-loses-focus-in-react-jsonschema-form-when-formdata-is-p), which is an advice about setting state, but I'm using functional components rather than class components, so I'm not sure if it's applicable.

The code looks like:

```
    import validator from "@rjsf/validator-ajv6"; 
    import Form from "@rjsf/mui";
    const ObjectFieldTemplate = (props) => {
        // some logic to be computed
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{props.title}</h3>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
                {props.properties.map(function (field) {
                    // logic to determine the style
                    return (<fieldset style={style} key={uuidv4()}>{field.content}</fieldset>);
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    const JsonSchemaForm = (props) => {
        // define schema and uiSchema
        const onSubmit = ({formData}, e) => {
            // some logic
        }
        const onError = (errors) => {console.log(errors);}
    
        return (<Form 
            schema={schema}
            validator={validator}
            formData={data}
            uiSchema={uiSchema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            onError={onError}
            templates={{ ObjectFieldTemplate }}
            />);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a random key that is re-computing everytime a re-render occour, it's not a matter or computation but it's the logic itself which is wrong. In general, never use `uuidv4()` as key, or any other function that might generate a different key. The key props must be stable on each re-render of the component, keep in mind that each time a rendering is activated all the function which are not "stable" (so, not inside an hook) is recomputed each time

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I'm not sure why, but it appears that setting `key={uuidv4()}` is an expensive computation step that forces the input box to be out of focus.